# Amazon S3 putobject for uploading a file to S3, does not return a promise

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, async-await

I have a function that uses Amazon S3 putobject to upload a file to S3, but this does not return a promise which I need to await successful completion after which I can then load a modal with the results (success or failure).

I have tried various async await promise permutations on the s3 function but none work with the .on httpUploadProgress.

```
s3.putObject(params)
        .on("httpUploadProgress", (progressEvent, response) => {
          const percent = parseInt(
            (100 * progressEvent.loaded) / progressEvent.total
          )
          setuploadprog(percent)
          if (percent === 100) {
            setuploadsuccess(1)
          }
        })
        .send((err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack)
            setuploadsuccess(2)
          } else {
            console.log(data)
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `send` with a callback. Do use the `promise` method instead:

```
s3.putObject(params)
    .on("httpUploadProgress", (progressEvent, response) => {
        const percent = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
        setuploadprog(percent)
    })
    .promise()
    .then(data => {
        setuploadsuccess(1);
        return data;
    }, err => {
        setuploadsuccess(2);
        throw err;
    });
```

Comment: Hi Bergi, I want to add the return promise to state. It is possible?

Comment: Sure, just `return` it?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here. Can you explain with code example?

Comment: No, I think I didn't understand what you are looking for. What exactly do you want to do with the promise? Where do you want to `await` it? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64849271/edit) to include more code, or [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if it's a separate topic.

Comment: I do not want the model to be fire before the file upload it is still fireing

Comment: setuploadsuccess(1); is still fireing before promise

Comment: Hi Bergi, Yes I want to await it.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the model to be fire*"? Please ask a new question with the full code you're using and a clear description what's not working. And yes, you can just `await` the promise that's returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
...await s3
.putObject(params)
```

Solve the issue by myself.